# copy image on windows using php script without modifying creation date

Tags: php, windows

I created a small php script to categorize picture by folder/date in Windows.
all is working great, files goes to the good place BUT it changes my "created date", wich I want to keep intact.

I use a very simple php copy() function.

I've use the touch() + filectime but still cannot change the creation date of file

any idea ?

Comment: Why not try `rename();` instead? `copy();` makes a copy of a file, rename moves it.

Answer (score 0):

from php.net:

```
It's worth noting that copy() sets the destination file's last modified time/date.
```

what is the problem of using this?

```
clearstatcache();
$oldstamp = filemtime("file.txt");
copy("file.txt","newfolder/file.txt");
touch("newfolder/file.txt",$oldstamp);
```

Comment: I'm still looking for a way to change the creation date from php.
my gallery is then viewed with Picasa wich read the creation date.

Comment: did you check my code? filemtime (m instead c) and clearstatcache?

Comment: yes I did, but the touch() still only affect what I don't need :)